# define condition for square root

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

This macro is for computing `sqrt(x)`,

```
#define SQRT(x)     ((x)<=0.0||(x)!=(x)?0.0:sqrt(x))
```

I can't understand in which case the second condition `(x)!=(x)` 
may be true?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`(x) != (x)` will be true if `x` is a [IEEE 754 Not-a-number (NaN)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN). I.e. this macro tries to coerce the result to 0.0 for arguments values for which square root is not defined. The [sqrt(3) Linux man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sqrt.3.html#RETURN_VALUE) summarizes the return values nicely:

> **RETURN VALUE**
>
> On success, these functions return the square root of x.
>
> - If `x` is a NaN, a NaN is returned.
> - If `x` is +0 (-0), +0 (-0) is returned.
> - If `x` is positive infinity, positive infinity is returned.
> - If `x` is less than -0, a domain error occurs, and a NaN is returned.

Therefore this expression makes sure that instead of NaN, 0 would be returned for the 1st and the 4th cases, and additionally, `errno` be untouched and that no floating point exception would occur.

---

(BTW this weird macro is not safe to use if you have side effects in the macro argument, so it'd better be replaced by an inline function or similar)

Comment: i.e. avoid macros